# simplifying math equation with factorials

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

I am trying to understand how simplified that equation:
$$\frac{(x-2)!}{(x-4)!}-46=\frac{x!}{(x-1)!}$$

In my book it was solved like this:

[image: solution in text]

but I really don't understand how it happened? Where did $(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$ come from  in first fraction? It looks like I missed something fundamental about factorials...

Comment: The author is just writing out the product $n! = n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$ when $n = x - 2$ in the numerator and $n = x - 4$ in the denominator.

Comment: As an aside, the solution is $x=10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{(x-2)!}{(x-4)!}-46=\frac{x!}{(x-1)!}\iff \frac{(x-2)!}{(x-4)!}-\frac{x!}{(x-1)!}-46=0$$
$$\frac{(x-2)!}{(x-4)!}-\frac{x!}{(x-1)!}-46= \frac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}\cdot \frac{(x-2)!}{(x-4)!}-\frac{x!}{(x-1)!}-46=
$$
$$=\frac{[(x-2)(x-3)]\cdot(x-1)!}{(x-1)!}-\frac{x\cdot(x-1)!}{(x-1)!}-\frac{46(x-1)!}{(x-1)!}=(x-2)(x-3)-x-46
$$